# Remove icehockey synonym mapping to hockey and make it as the main tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hockey versus Ice Hockey - should they be synonyms?](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40/hockey-versus-ice-hockey-should-they-be-synonyms)

Apparently [this meta post](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40/hockey-versus-ice-hockey-should-they-be-synonyms) has resulted in icehockey being mapped as a synonym to hockey.

May I remind that outside of the US, [Hockey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_hockey) is a *different* game with no bearing whatsoever to Ice Hockey?

I don't see why Ice Hockey should be a synonym to Hockey.

Comment: Is there a reason that this deserves a separate question? Maybe this should be discussed in the original thread so we have all arguments for/against in the same place.

Comment: @MarcusSwope previous question was already marked as completed - didn't make sense to continue there.

Comment: @Sathya this was discussed in chat and in the meta post. non ice hockey types should use a specifier (field-hockey,floor-hockey, roller-hockey, tonsil-hockey)

Comment: @waxeagle Why should **non** ice-hockey types use a specifier? Whatever happened to targetting the global audience?

Comment: I believe Grace Note's point was that "hockey" is a pretty generic term that can cover most any hockey-related sport.

Comment: Feel free to [join us in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2433/the-clubhouse) to discuss more.

Comment: @MichaelMyers no, it was just a thought that I had while going through the questions. Not a huge sports buff and I don't see myself using the site the site often.

Comment: I don't know if "outside the U.S." would be an accurate statement. Perhaps "not everywhere" - but in Canada, Scandinavia, Russia, and I would expect most of Europe you would find an unqualified "hockey" to mean ice hockey.

Comment: @Sathya Just because I marked it complete, doesn't mean I'm not open to reversing the decision. I'm fine with discussing it there (and I even asked someone to present that argument more clearly there).

Answer (score 0):

I've gone and removed the synonym for now and remapped the existing ice hockey questions to [ice-hockey](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ice-hockey). We can still deliberate, but I suggest we continue that discussion [in the original question](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40/hockey-versus-ice-hockey-should-they-be-synonyms).

I'm marking this as completed because I removed the synonym, *not* because a final decision is being made. Also gonna close this as an effective duplicate just to funnel people to the right place.