# Edit question to add correct tags

Tags: support

I have asked a [question](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/350/why-were-artificial-turfs-introduced) about (field) hockey. But the tags [hockey](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hockey) and [tag:field hockey] does not exist currently. And since I don't have enough reputation on the site to create new tags, I have currently tagged it as [general](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/general). Could some one with enough rep edit the question and add appropriate tags.

Comment: On a related note, the tag [tag:general] shouldn't exist at all. Only one locked question still has the tag; I've flagged it to request a moderator to remove the tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I added the [field-hockey](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/field-hockey) tag. (Note that tags are single words, so they use dashes, not spaces.

Pursuant to [this question](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/q/73/16) which brings up an excellent point, and [this question](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40/hockey-versus-ice-hockey-should-they-be-synonyms) which contains the discussion for the first, I have not added the [hockey](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hockey) tag. I see you've already had some input on the discussion thread, so I won't rehash the situation here as well.